# find -exec {} vs. find -exec '{}'

Tags: bash, find

I noticed in the man pages for find, that the {} always have single quotes around them.

`find -exec '{}' \;`

The description states:

> Notice
>          that the braces are enclosed in single quote marks to protect them from
>          interpretation  as  shell  script punctuation.   The semicolon is simi-
>          larly protected by the use of a backslash

I have never had an issue using just `find -exec {} \;`
What is an example where the single quotes are required.

Comment: My persoal `find` usage is very rudimentary, but I habitually backslash the curly brackets: `find . -exec whatever \{\} \;`

Comment: See Gilles answer on the duplicate question, he covers it there.